# java.security.ProviderException: point is not on curve

Tags: java

I get this exception when send http request to third-party services using okhttp client, but not  show the exception always.

```java
Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: point is not on curve
    at jdk.crypto.ec/sun.security.ec.ECDHKeyAgreement.validate(ECDHKeyAgreement.java:146)
    at jdk.crypto.ec/sun.security.ec.ECDHKeyAgreement.deriveKeyImpl(ECDHKeyAgreement.java:222)
    at jdk.crypto.ec/sun.security.ec.ECDHKeyAgreement.engineGenerateSecret(ECDHKeyAgreement.java:169)
    at jdk.crypto.ec/sun.security.ec.ECDHKeyAgreement.engineGenerateSecret(ECDHKeyAgreement.java:201)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.generateSecret(KeyAgreement.java:660)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ECDHKeyExchange$ECDHEKAKeyDerivation.t13DeriveKey(ECDHKeyExchange.java:457)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ECDHKeyExchange$ECDHEKAKeyDerivation.deriveKey(ECDHKeyExchange.java:419)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$T13ServerHelloConsumer.consume(ServerHello.java:1254)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$ServerHelloConsumer.onServerHello(ServerHello.java:988)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$ServerHelloConsumer.consume(ServerHello.java:876)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:422)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:183)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1144)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1055)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:395)
```

The code send http request:

```java
public static String request(Request request, HttpTimeout httpTimeout) {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = HttpClientSingleton.getOkHttpClient();
        if (httpTimeout != null) {
            okHttpClient = okHttpClient
                    .newBuilder()
                    .writeTimeout(httpTimeout.writeTimeout)
                    .readTimeout(httpTimeout.readTimeout)
                    .connectTimeout(httpTimeout.connectTimeout)
                    .build();
        }
        Call call = okHttpClient.newCall(request);
        try (Response response = call.execute()) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
                return responseBody.string();
            } else {
                LOGGER.error("request {} ,response {} ,body {}", request.toString(), response.toString(), response.body() == null ? "" : response.body().string());
                return "";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(request.toString(), e);
        }
    }
```

And this is okhttp client configuration, in this configuraion we have trusted all certificate and does't verify any hostname.

```java
private static class OkHttpClientSingletonHolder {
        private static final okhttp3.OkHttpClient OK_HTTP_CLIENT;

        static {
            ThreadPoolExecutor executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                    new SynchronousQueue<>(), Util.threadFactory("OkHttp Dispatcher", false));


            Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher(executorService);
            dispatcher.setMaxRequestsPerHost(250);
            dispatcher.setMaxRequests(2000);

            OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = new okhttp3.OkHttpClient
                    .Builder()
                    .eventListener(DelegateEventListener.getForCoreInstance())
                    .dispatcher(dispatcher)
                    .dns(CacheDnsResolver.INSTANCE)
                    .followRedirects(false)
                    .followSslRedirects(false)
                    .connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(128, 900, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                    .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .writeTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .sslSocketFactory(SSL.sslSocketFactory, SSL.x509TrustManager)
                    .hostnameVerifier(SSL.hostnameVerifier);

            if (ComponentStatus.isTraceEnable()) {
                clientBuilder.addInterceptor(new OkhttpTracingInterceptor());
            }
            OK_HTTP_CLIENT = clientBuilder.build();
        }
    }
```

It looks like ok, The point is this exception only occur sometimes.

Comment: show the code snippet

Comment: I have add the http client configuraion, but it looks like ok